# $(...).tabs is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I have this code on two pages on my site, but at one page the function doesn't work. Firebug shows me " $(...).tabs is not a function ". I don't understand why, can anyone tell me what is wrong ?

this is working:
http://www.invat-online.net/variante-rezolvate

this is not working:
http://www.invat-online.net/variante-explicate-limba-romana/varianta-01

Here is the code:

```html
<div id="tabss">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#SubiectI">Subiect I</a></li>
        <li><a href="#SubiectII">Subiect II</a></li>
        <li><a href="#SubiectIII">Subiect III</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="SubiectI">content here</div>
    <div id="SubiectII">content here</div>
    <div id="SubiectIII">content here</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tabss").tabs();
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You have relative paths to javascript files:

`javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js`

change them to absolute paths because you're using `mod_rewrite` module

`/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js`

In first link the server is looking to the directory

`http://www.invat-online.net/javascript/my_js_file.js` (which exists)

but in the second one the path will be

`http://www.invat-online.net/variante-explicate-limba-romana/javascript/my_js_file.js` which do not exists

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm amazed, I tormented my mind 5 days .....

I am a beginner but here I found solutions every time

Thank you again!

Comment: Alex if this was the answer then please mark it so.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

In my case:

I was using

```
jquery-ui-1.10.3.minimal.min.js
```

instead of

```
jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
```

minimal version does not include ui.tabs.js, hence no ui.tabs function. Hope this helps someone else out there

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the jQuery UI js and css is not loading.

Try changing the path in you `<script>` tags to either the directory above `../javascript` or the website root `/javascript`.

```
<script src="/javascript/head.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="/stylesheets/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Thanks, the path was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your first demo loads:

```
http://www.invat-online.net/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
```

Your second demo attempts to load:

```
http://www.invat-online.net/variante-explicate-limba-romana/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
```

The last one results in a 404. You should correct the path of the later, perhaps instructing it to find jQuery UI in one directory above the current: `../jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js`.

Comment: <script src="/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css" />

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@section scripts{
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabss").tabs();
});
}
```

Put `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` in the `<body></body>` of your layout.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

The error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function` may also be produced when in a Django project on the Admin area and using django-tabbed-admin under the following setup:

- Django = 1.10.5
- django-tabbed-admin=1.0.4
- DEFAULT_JQUERY_UI_JS = 'tabbed_admin/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js'

The problem is that the code in jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js for this Django lib is as follows:

```js
    /*! jQuery UI - v1.11.4 - 2015-07-27
    (...)*/
    jQuery = jQuery || django.jQuery.noConflict(false);
```

and the code on django-tabbed-admin uses it this way (change_form.html):

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(window).scrollTop()
            $('#tabs').tabs({
                {% if add %}
                // when adding, don't select a tab by default, we'll do it ourselves
                // by finding the first available tab.
                selected: -1
                {% endif %}
            });
        (....)
        })(django.jQuery);
    </script>
    <!-- end admin_tabs stuff -->
```

To sort this out this should be what would be passed in to the IIFE instead of the (django.jQuery) as above:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            (....)
        })((typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined' && typeof window.django != 'undefined')
  ? django.jQuery
  : jQuery)
    </script>
    <!-- end admin_tabs stuff -->
```

I've [reported](https://github.com/omji/django-tabbed-admin/issues/35) this issue in the project and created a [PR](https://github.com/omji/django-tabbed-admin/pull/36) with a fix for it. Waiting on it to be approved, so in the meantime you can sort it following my simple fix.

I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

Check your page you might have loaded multiple versions of jQuery

Comment: Why does this happen? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I realized that I had jquery and bootstrap css imports that enter in conflict each other. Take a look to the ones you have imported and reduce those imports to the minimum to see which is the conflict.

Here there is an example of how to implement it, I took that example and worked, then I adapted to my application:

for jquery 1.9 (click on **view source** to see the code)
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

for jquery 1.8 (check the example at the end of the page)
http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/tabs/

Hope it helps!